# is this good to use realm database for Chat Application?

Tags: ios, core-data, realm, xmpp, xmppframework

I am developing one chat application but some confuse regarding database. I have no idea about how to expand core data module that provided by XMPPFramework(iOS) and in application i need some database changes like message count etc.. so **[realm database](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/)** is good option store my all message, rooster ,groups and other chat related setting ?

**Current scenario**

- Used default database that provided by [XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework)
- Do't find any solution for how to extend XMPPFramework database.

**Dev Tools**

- [ejabberd](https://www.ejabberd.im/) server used in backend.
- Xcode 8.3.3(Swift 3.0)

let me know your good suggestion regarding database and other points.

Comment: Well its cool. Its got notifications for updates deletions and insertions. So basically any change in the db is directly affecting the medium in which you are presenting the messages to the user. It also does not require paging, because realm arrays work differently than normal arrays (look for "realm paging"), but I'd still recommend implementing a little bit of paging as calculating cell sizes is a bit heavy. I've tried using it with a SignalR based chat. It has worked fine so far

Comment: Hi @DatForis
Have you any example regarding realm db and xmpp for iOS?

Comment: Hey @JayMehta Have you used realm with xmpp in your iOS app? If yes then can you please share your feedback about usability?

Comment: hi @JayMehta if you have any sample code for retrieve chat history from https://www.ejabberd.im/ server

Comment: nope - @AbishekThangaraj